# ng-bootstrap - adding classes to a tab-pane

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am building an Angular application that makes use of Bootstrap's flex-box implementation to vertically fill the available space, however there is one case in ng-bootstrap where I can't work out how to apply a `flex-fill` class. I'm using the ng-bootstrap implementation for a tab control:

```
<div class="card border-primary flex-fill">
    <div class="card-header bg-primary">
        <ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
            <li ngbNavItem>
                <a ngbNavLink class="text-dark">One</a>
                <ng-template ngbNavContent>One</ng-template>
            </li>
            <li ngbNavItem>
                <a ngbNavLink class="text-dark">Two</a>
                <ng-template ngbNavContent>Two</ng-template>
            </li>
            <li ngbNavItem>
                <a ngbNavLink class="text-dark">Three</a>
                <ng-template ngbNavContent>Three</ng-template>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="card-body d-flex flex-column"></div>
</div>
```

The control generates a `<div class="tab-pane active">...</div>` element within the `[ngbNavOutlet]` element, but I need to apply `flex-fill` so it should be `tab-pane active flex-fill`.

Any ideas how to apply additional classes to the tab-pane?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure css/sass, like that :

```
.tab-pane{
   @extend .flex-fill;
}
```